# Start MySql if it's not active

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have some problem, don't know why every day about 06:08-06:24 my mysql just stops:

```
2021-03-29T06:24:22.398643Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
2021-03-29T06:24:22.398662Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
2021-03-29T06:24:22.398666Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
2021-03-29T06:24:22.398671Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2021-03-29T06:24:22.399095Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2021-03-29T06:24:22.401054Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'validate_password'
...
...
```

I try to make cronjob to start mysql when it stops, does this script will do it?

```
* * * * * systemctl is-active -quiet mysql || sudo service mysql start
```

If is active it won't do nothing but if "is not active" it will make "sudo service mysql start" ?

ANSWER:

For some reasons, I do not know yet why, plugin 'WP Crontrol' in Wordpress was responsible for base stop every day ....

Comment: Could you post more logs, e.g. 10 minutes before and after 2021-03-29T06:24:22.398643Z ?

Comment: there is nothing before ... this is beginning of error.log for mysql .. no I see some dns.cyberium.cc in nginx logs. DDOS?

Comment: What do you see in `mysqld.log`? If your website is public, you will see a lot of penetration tests in your logs. It might not be the cause of your issue. But you have to keep this in mind too.

Comment: I just today turned on mysql.log ... but ... will this cronjob start mysql if for some reason it will tomorrow shot down?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is running on the machine? For systemd you have `Restart=on-failure` https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: However restarting it will just hide the problem, not solve it.

Comment: What operating system is in use? Is it using systemd? How did you install MySQL? Is there any other cron job that might trigger this behaviour? What does system log say for that point of time?

Comment: It's Ubuntu 18.04 ... I know it's just hide problem ... yes, I also use wordpress plugin for cronjobs :) - and mysql start stopped when I start using it ( populate table from which wordpres cronjob takes some entry end then delete them from that table ) ... today table will be empty and if problem will stop, there will be someone to blame :)